# CSS-HTML viewport page

Tags: html, css, viewport, smartphone

i'm working on HTML page and, at the smartphone rendering, the page display a white part at the end of the contents(Note, contents ends at the background). 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI27T.png)

I'm using the following CSS/HTML rules:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0" >    
@media only screen {

    html{width:100%;
    height:100%;
    }

    body {background-image:url("sf.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:auto;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    }`
```

Could someone know why it works like that?

Comment: background-size: auto keeps the background image in the original width/height ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `background-size:cover; background-position: center center`

This expand the image to cover all the area